# CarrierWave: Read-only upload field?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, carrierwave

I'm trying to create an ActiveRecord model where CarrierWave is used in a read-only fashion, i.e. a user creates a record with a file, and the file cannot be changed after creation of the record.

I've tried setting the attribute to `attr_readonly` in the model, but when testing it in RSpec, it showed that the field was still able to be changed (specifically, a comparison of `@myclass.file.url` showed that the location of the file would change if I attempted to upload a new file) . I also looked at the possibility of using validations to check whether the file param in the edit action matched the file field in the model, but that didn't seem to pan out either.

```
class MyClass < ActiveRecord::Base
  mount_uploader :file, MyClassUploader
  attr_readonly :file

  validates :title, presence: true
  validates :description, presence: true
  validates :file, presence: true
end
```

My migration for this class looks like:

```
class CreateMyClasses < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :myclasses do |t|
      t.string :title
      t.string :description
      t.string :file

      t.timestamps null: false
    end
  end
end
```

How can I ensure that once my model has been created, the file component can't be changed, but all other fields can?

Comment: You can remove the upload button once user has uploaded a file

Comment: Why not just hide the file field in the edit form?